# Regex - exclude word within string

Tags: regex, string-matching

I want to match everything except “eps1@“ within this string:

```
HelpMe_pleas3_eps1@
```

I tried `[^eps1@]` but this matched everything except every instance of “e” “p” “s” “1” “@“.  I just want “eps1@“ excluded.

Comment: try: `[^(eps1@)]`

Comment: Hey Nir - thanks for your response.  Unfortunately I got the same result - it doesn't exclude just eps1@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it, depending on what you really need.

Using `(.*)eps1@` you match everything before "eps1@" in the first capturing group. See [demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/JcrL4V/1).

Using `(.*)eps1@(.*)` you match everything before and after "eps1@" in the first and second capturing groups. See [demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/JcrL4V/2).

If "eps1@" occurs multiple times, you can use this regex:

```
(?:[^eps1@]|e(?!ps1@)|(?<!e)p(?!s1@)|(?<!ep)s(?!1@)|(?<!eps)1(?!@)|(?<!eps1)@)+
```

That means:

- `[^eps1@]` any character but "e", "p", "s", "1", and "@"; OR
- `e(?!ps1@)` the character "e" if not followed by "ps1@"; OR
- `(?<!e)p(?!s1@)` the character "p" if not preceded by "e" and not followed by "s1@"; OR
- and so forth.

See [demo #3](https://regex101.com/r/Pfyo73/1).

But have you considered just replacing "eps1@" with "" into your source string?

P.S. For the next questions I'd suggest you to be more precise on the language you're using.

Comment: Thanks!!  Sorry I wasn't clear.  Ultimately, I wanted to be able to extract/match "HelpMe_please3_" so that I can replace "eps1!@" with something else.  I was able to achieve this by using `(.*)[^eps1@]`.